# Testing multiple libGdx apps on device

Tags: libgdx

I've got two apps I want to upload to my physical device (android) but one replaces the other. I can't figure out why it replaces the other one. Any ideas?

Comment: Same package name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android places applications into a directory that's dependent on the Application ID of the app, so if you have 2 apps with the same Application ID they'll override each other.

You need to change the Application ID in the Gradle file for Android - see
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id